# how to merge slider handles with lines in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to achieve this kind of result but do you give me a clue how can I do it with less effort in react?

[sliders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fl0R8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render SVG on the background.

I use functions for building a cubic bezier curves from [this article](https://francoisromain.medium.com/smooth-a-svg-path-with-cubic-bezier-curves-e37b49d46c74).

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-bhabha-zbbjng?file=/src/App.js)

[image: screenshot]